# parsing json file with potential corrupted record and sorting by id to output first n lines - cleaner logic

Tags: python, json

messy json file is parsed and should output the N highest
record IDs & scores by score in descending order, highest score first.

the code works but i wonder if there is better readability, help me refactor it.

The function takes 2 args - the data file path and num of scores to return:

```
python myprogram.py highest score_recs.data 25
```

The input data file has a record per line. Each line has the following structure:

```
<score>: <json string>
```

If the line has a score that would make it part of the highest scores,
then the remainder of the line *must* be parsable as JSON, and
there must be an id key at the top level of this JSON doc.

An example data file could look like this:

```
10622876: {"umbrella": 99180, "name": "24490249af01e145437f2f64d5ddb9c04463c033", "value": 12354, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 58874, "time": 615416, "id": "3c867674494e4a7aac9247a9d9a2179c"}
13214012: {"umbrella": 924902, "name": "70dd4d9494d1cd0362e123ce90f4053726b29e97", "value": 976852, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 3255, "time": 156309, "id": "085a11e1b82b441184f4a193a3c9a13c"}
11446512: {"umbrella": 727371, "name": "8e21427b2350023079835361dce03cdea95a2983", "value": 70801, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 1730, "time": 496866, "id": "84a0ccfec7d1475b8bfcae1945aea8f0"}
11025835: === THIS IS NOT JSON and should error
11269569: {"umbrella": 902167, "name": "e4898b9bf79831cf36811917a797ef0fcf3af636", "value": 593180, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 58736, "time": 1014495, "id": "7ec85fe3aa3c4dd599e23111e7abf5c1"}
11027069: {"umbrella": 990975, "name": "8aa306fb59e275a7e39debb1d5113ff411df22ad", "value": 67842, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 60161, "time": 225413, "id": "f812d487de244023a6a713e496a8427d"}
```

initially json file is not sorted by scores.

steps:

- the bad json error is thrown only if there is bad record within the first minimum n unsorted lines,i.e. in the original json
- otherwise, even if there is bad record but not within the first n unsorted lines i can keep all the records and parse it
- sort it by scores in desc order, then keep the first n
  output a list of dicts, each dict has 2 fields - score,id

For example, if run with an N of 3 and 4th entry is bad json, it still works and produce:

python myprogram highest score_recs.data 3

```
[
    {
        "score": 13214012,
        "id": "085a11e1b82b441184f4a193a3c9a13c"
    },
    {
        "score": 11446512,
        "id": "84a0ccfec7d1475b8bfcae1945aea8f0"
    },
    {
        "score": 11269569,
        "id": "7ec85fe3aa3c4dd599e23111e7abf5c1"
    }
]
```

But when run with an N that includes that line, it would error:

$ python myprogram highest score_recs.data 10

```
invalid json format No JSON object could be decoded
 THIS IS NOT JSON
```

The scores are unique across the data
set * Scores can repeat, but you should only count the id of the *last* line processed
as the “winning” id. if score is not present it should give format error.

scores.data:

```
10622876: {"umbrella": 99180, "name": "24490249af01e145437f2f64d5ddb9c04463c033", "value": 12354, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 58874, "time": 615416, "id": "3c867674494e4a7aac9247a9d9a2179c"}
13214012: {"umbrella": 924902, "name": "70dd4d9494d1cd0362e123ce90f4053726b29e97", "value": 976852, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 3255, "time": 156309, "id": "085a11e1b82b441184f4a193a3c9a13c"}
11446512: {"umbrella": 727371, "name": "8e21427b2350023079835361dce03cdea95a2983", "value": 70801, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 1730, "time": 496866, "id": "84a0ccfec7d1475b8bfcae1945aea8f0"}
11025835: === THIS IS NOT JSON and should error if this line is part of the result set, but is ok if it not ==
11269569: {"umbrella": 902167, "name": "e4898b9bf79831cf36811917a797ef0fcf3af636", "value": 593180, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 58736, "time": 1014495, "id": "7ec85fe3aa3c4dd599e23111e7abf5c1"}
11027069: {"umbrella": 990975, "name": "8aa306fb59e275a7e39debb1d5113ff411df22ad", "value": 67842, "payload": "........", "date_stamp": 60161, "time": 225413, "id": "f812d487de244023a6a713e496a8427d"}
```

the python code:

```
import json
import sys

def main(filename, n):
    res = []

    main = dict()
    cnt = 1
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            id, content = line.split(":", 1)

            try:
                id = int(id)
            except ValueError:
                raise "Format error - no id"

            if "IS NOT JSON" in content:
                print("found bad json - check if we can continue")
                if cnt <= n:
                    # here this means the original unsorted json file has bad json within the first needed n lines - so we need to throw error as per the condition
                    raise "ERROR: THIS IS NOT JSON"
                else:
                    print("ah no, its good")

            else:
                try:  # need try here cuz when json.loads() sees bad json - it will throw jsondecode error, that i need to catch
                    newd = json.loads(content)
                    main[id] = newd
                    cnt += 1
                except:
                    print(
                        "keep pushing! that bad json is after the minimum n we need - so we need to record all jsons then sort then get the first n"
                    )

    main = [[k, v] for k, v in main.items()]
    main = sorted(main, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])

    #get the first sorted n items, create a dict [score][id]
    main = dict(main[:n])

    for k, v in main.items():
        score = k
        id = v["id"]
        newd = dict()
        newd["score"] = score
        newd["id"] = id

        res.append(newd)    

    return res
    
arg_list = (sys.argv)
    
filenamepath = str(arg_list[1])
num_lines = int(arg_list[2])
    
main(filenamepath, num_lines)
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight, done sir, thx u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## name your module

```
$ python myprogram.py ...
```

Yeah, that's not a name.

Maybe `high_score_report.py` ?

## name your function

```
def main...
```

This is a terrific name for "first function that will execute".
But its body is entirely too long --
it contains *all* of your business logic.
If you retain the name `main`, then this function should
pretty much immediately delegate to better named code
whose name describes the logic.

## don't rename

```
def main(filename, n):
    res = []

    main = dict()
```

Uggh! First `main` is a module-level function, then
we shadow that with a local variable.
No. Don't do that.
Pick a new name.
It doesn't matter to the machine,
but it *does* matter to the maintenance engineer
who is reading this code months down the road.
Especially if the engineer has a phone
[conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F)
about the code.

Similarly, further down in your code,
prefer an identifier of `id_` rather than shadowing the builtin
[id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

---

## crack argv

```
arg_list = (sys.argv)
```

The extra `(` `)` parens are weird and distracting.
Please format with
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
to remove such artifacts.

Also, renaming the familiar `sys.argv` doesn't seem to help humans much.

### use an `if __name__` guard

```
arg_list = (sys.argv)
    
filenamepath = str(arg_list[1])
num_lines = int(arg_list[2])
    
main(filenamepath, num_lines)
```

This will run when other modules, such as your
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase),
`import` this module.
Use a guard to prevent such side effects.

Also this is too long, and not just because the `str()` is redundant.
Rewrite with slice + tuple unpack:

```
def main(filename, n):
    ...
if __name__ == "__main__":`
    filenamepath, num_lines = sys.argv[1:]
    main(filenamepath, int(num_lines))
```

Or better, add type annotation and let
[typer](https://pypi.org/project/typer)
worry about cracking argv:

```
from pathlib import Path
import typer

def main(filename: Path, n: int):
    ...
if __name__ == "__main__":`
    typer.run(main)
```

---

## do one thing well

Each function should have a
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).
Here, you appear to be doing several things:

1. Identify well-formed lines that start with integer + colon.
2. Identify "bad JSON" lines, distinguishing between "late bad" and fatal "early bad".
3. Report on just the top-N entries.

In a bash script we might organize this as a multi-step pipeline
using the `|` pipe character.
In python it is often convenient to chain generators together.
So we might have:

```
from operator import itemgetter
    ...
    def get_scored_content(self):
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                score, content = line.split(":", 1)
                yield int(score), content

    def get_json_ids(self):
        for i, (score, content) in enumerate(self.get_scored_content()):
            if i < self.n:
                d = json.loads(content)
            else:
                try:
                    d = json.loads(content)
                except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                    continue
            yield score, d["id"]

    def get_top_entries(self):
        return sorted(self.get_json_ids(), reverse=True, key=itemgetter(0))[:self.n]
```

Now a simple comprehension can easily turn
those N entries into the desired list of dicts.

Note the use of the common
[itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=getter#operator.itemgetter) idiom.

### use accurate identifiers

You wrote `id` when representing a `score`.
I renamed it in the above code.

---

## display results

The OP code evaluates `main` for side effects
and discards its `dict` result.
You probably wanted to send the result
to stdout or to a file.

---

This module appears to achieve many of its design goals.
It has accumulated some technical debt and
would benefit from a bit of refactoring.

I would be reluctant to delegate maintenance tasks
on this codebase in its current form.

Comment: i did not even think that main inside main is bad lol. thx u. totally overlooked.